# Show first column even when all others return no data

Tags: sql

I need to display the first column of data, even when the remaining columns of data have no values in the results.

I have tried a variety of functions to achieve my result, but have not made any progress.

```
SELECT 
  Distinct dbo.ae_i_inv_e.cycle_code AS Section,
  Sum(dbo.ae_i_loc_e.qty) As Quantity_On_Hand,
  Sum(dbo.ae_i_inv_w.whse_cost) AS Average_Cost,
  SUM (dbo.ae_i_loc_e.qty * dbo.ae_i_inv_w.whse_cost) AS Cost_On_Hand,
  Count (dbo.ae_i_inv_e.part) AS Items


  FROM
(  dbo.ae_i_inv_e
  Left Outer JOIN dbo.ae_i_loc_e ON (dbo.ae_i_inv_e.multitenant_id = 
dbo.ae_i_loc_e.multitenant_id)
  AND (dbo.ae_i_inv_e.part = dbo.ae_i_loc_e.part))
  Left Outer JOIN dbo.ae_i_inv_w ON (dbo.ae_i_loc_e.multitenant_id = 
dbo.ae_i_inv_w.multitenant_id)
  AND (dbo.ae_i_inv_w.multitenant_id = dbo.ae_i_inv_e.multitenant_id)
  AND (dbo.ae_i_loc_e.part = dbo.ae_i_inv_w.part)
  AND (dbo.ae_i_inv_w.part = dbo.ae_i_inv_e.part)

WHERE dbo.ae_i_inv_e.multitenant_id = '2824' AND
    dbo.ae_i_inv_e.active = 'N'

GROUP BY
  dbo.ae_i_inv_e.cycle_code

ORDER BY
  dbo.ae_i_inv_e.cycle_code
```

Actual Results
Section  Quantity_on_hand  Average_cost  Cost_on_hand   Items

Expected results

```
Section  Quantity_on_hand  Average_cost  Cost_on_hand   Items
A           0                 0               0           0
B           0                 0               0           0
C           0                 0               0           0
D           0                 0               0           0
E           0                 0               0           0
```

Comment: Will you add what your data looks like, thank you

Comment: I would check the predicate (`where`) and `left outer join`s if they are returning rows. Do they return rows without the `group by` clause?

Comment: Your query should return all cycle codes that meet your `where` conditions.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: When I look at Active data as 'Y', I receive all cycle codes, but all rows and columns contain data.  For the Active data as 'N', I know I have no data at the moment, but I need to show that.

Answer (score 0):

You query will return all cycle codes in the data.  If you have a set list, then include it in the query:

```
SELECT v.Section,
       SUM(l.qty) As Quantity_On_Hand,
       SUM(w.whse_cost) AS Average_Cost,
       SUM(l.qty * w.whse_cost) AS Cost_On_Hand,
       COUNT(e.part) AS Items
FROM (VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E')) v(section) LEFT JOIN
     dbo.ae_i_inv_e e
     ON e.cycle_code = v.section LEFT JOIN
     dbo.ae_i_loc_e l
     ON e.multitenant_id = l.multitenant_id AND
        e.part = l.part LEFT JOIN
     dbo.ae_i_inv_w w
     ON l.multitenant_id = w.multitenant_id AND
        w.multitenant_id = e.multitenant_id AND
        l.part = w.part AND
        w.part = e.part
WHERE e.multitenant_id = '2824' AND
      e.active = 'N'
GROUP BY v.section
ORDER BY v.section;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.  (I hope I replaced them correctly.)
- The first table has the sections that you want.
- Your `JOIN` conditions seem redundant, but I did not change them.
- `'2824'` should probably be `2824` (without quotes), if the vaue is a number.

Comment: Gordon,  Your query executed, but I received the same results as before.  All blank data, except the column headers.  I made the changes you suggested and also receive the same results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.Section,
    ISNULL(COALESCE(a.Quantity_On_Hand, b.Quantity_On_Hand), 0) as Quantity_On_Hand,
    ISNULL(COALESCE(a.cost_on_hand, b.cost_on_hand), 0) as cost_on_hand,
    ISNULL(COALESCE(a.items, b.items), 0) as items

FROM (
    Select *
    FROM (
    VALUES 
        ('A', NULL, NULL, NULL), 
        ('B', NULL, NULL, NULL), 
        ('C', NULL, NULL, NULL), 
        ('E', NULL, NULL, NULL), 
        ('G', NULL, NULL, NULL), 
        ('N', NULL, NULL, NULL), 
        ('P', NULL, NULL, NULL), 
        ('S', NULL, NULL, NULL), 
        ('T', NULL, NULL, NULL), 
        ('U', NULL, NULL, NULL), 
        ('V', NULL, NULL, NULL)
    ) inv(Section, Quantity_On_Hand, cost_on_hand, items)
) AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        e.cycle_code AS Section,
        isnull(Sum (loc.qty),0) As Quantity_On_Hand,
        isnull(SUM (loc.qty * w.whse_cost),0) AS Cost_On_Hand,
        Count (e.part) AS Items

    FROM 
        ae_i_inv_e e

        LEFT OUTER JOIN ae_i_loc_e loc ON 
        e.multitenant_id = loc.multitenant_id AND 
        e.part = loc.part

        LEFT OUTER JOIN ae_i_inv_w w ON 
        e.multitenant_id = w.multitenant_id AND 
        e.part = w.part 

    WHERE 
        e.active = 'N' AND
        e.multitenant_id = '2824'

    GROUP BY
        e.cycle_code)
AS b ON a.section = b.Section

Order By
    a.section
```

This resolved the issue I was having.